# Using filter on vector of variant

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to iterate over filtered (by type) `std::vector<std::variant<T...>>`.
Problem I hit is that the `std::get` is overloaded function(and has many implicit template args I need to type out) so I would need to cast it to something specific.

This seems ugly and hard so I tried to hack together `holds_alternative` and `get` into a functor that returns a view of `filter`( for `holds_alternative`) and `transform`( for `get`) views.
That does not work.

Questions:

- can I do what I want without providing my structs and without ugly casts needed to specify `std::get` overload, ugly need to specify all template arguments to `std::holds_alternative`, `std::get`?
- if answer to previous quesion is no: why does my attempt does not work

note:

my code does not attempt to handle properly `const` and `&&` like `std::get` does, I am fine with it working only on `const` l-values.

My [code](https://godbolt.org/z/sjn7qvoTE):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct Red {
  int x = 0;
};

struct Green {
  int x = 1;
};

struct Blue {
  int x = 2;
};

using Color = std::variant<Red, Green, Blue>;

template <typename T> struct engaged_t {
  template <typename... Ts>
  constexpr bool operator()(const std::variant<Ts...> &variant) {
    return std::holds_alternative<T>(variant);
  }
};

template <typename T> inline constexpr auto engaged = engaged_t<T>{};

template <typename T> struct variant_get_t {
  template <typename... Ts>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(std::variant<Ts...> &variant) {
    return std::get<T>(variant);
  }
};

template <typename T> inline constexpr auto variant_get = variant_get_t<T>{};

template <typename T> struct variant_filter_t {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto variant_filter = variant_filter_t<T>{};

template <typename R, typename T>
decltype(auto) operator|(const R &r, variant_filter_t<T>) {
  return r | std::views::filter(engaged<T>) |
         std::views::transform(variant_get<T>);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Color> colors{Red{}, Green{}, Blue{}, Green{}};
  // does not compile
  // for (const auto green: colors | variant_filter<Green>){
  //   std::cout << std::get<Green>(green).x << std::endl;
  // }

  // kaboom if we try to do anything, just to show we can pipe colors to
  // variant_get
  for (const auto bad_green : colors |
                                  std::views::transform(variant_get<Green>) |
                                  std::views::take(0)) {
  }
  // we can also pipe colors to engaged
  for (const auto bluev : colors | std::views::filter(engaged<Blue>)) {
    std::cout << std::get<Blue>(bluev).x << std::endl;
  }
  // and if we manually doe what variant_filter should_do that also seems to
  // work
  for (const auto blue : colors | std::views::filter(engaged<Blue>) |
                             std::views::transform(variant_get<Blue>)) {
    std::cout << blue.x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want a *functor* to have `filter` followed by the `transform` view?

Comment: This is a lot of questions. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to have a way to compose | std::views::filter(engaged<Blue>) |
                             std::views::transform(variant_get<Blue>) without need to type <Blue> twice.

Comment: @Barry: well if my assumption is correct I can not nicely write what I want without using custom structs I would like to know why functor does not work since when I do it "manually" it seems to work.

Comment: @Barry by manual I mean code after this comment in code :  and if we manually doe what variant_filter should_do that

Comment: You missed a `const` in `variant_get_t::operator()`, on the parameter

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ah, I never ever considered checking for stuff like that, I presumed I messed up some obscure ranges requirement... you can make it an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing `const R&` to forwarding reference `R&&` (and fixing typo), it works:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
decltype(auto) operator|(R&& r, variant_filter_t<T>) {
  return r | std::views::filter(engaged<T>)
           | std::views::transform(variant_get<T>);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Color> colors{Red{}, Green{}, Blue{}, Green{}};
  for (const auto green: colors | variant_filter<Green>){
     std::cout << green.x << std::endl;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W3YYa5arr)